# Transition on position property isn't working (bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i don't get this transition to work. The hover effect is working: the arrow moves to the left when hovered over "previous case". But the transition I set to smoothen the animation isn't taking effect at all.

```
.icon-left-open-big {position: relative;
                     transition: right 2s;}

.bottom-link-group:hover .icon-left-open-big {right: 10px;}
```

my html is:

```
<section class="fuss-nav">
  <div class="container-fluid abstand pb-5">
   <div class="row no-gutters mx-sm-3 mx-md-2">

    <div class="col-3 px-1 col-sm-4">
      <a href="#" class="bottom-link-group">
        <i class="icon-left-open-big pfeil"></i>
        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">previous case</span>
      </a>
    </div>

       <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
           <a href="#" class="back-to-top">back to top</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3 px-1 col-sm-4 text-right">
        <a href="#" class="bottom-link-group">
          <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">next case</span>
          <i class="icon-right-open-big pfeil"></i>
        </a>  
    </div>

    </div>  
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the initial value which is `right:0px`, because transition works when changing a value of a property from something to something else

see code sample

```css
.icon-left-open-big,.icon-right-open-big {
  position: relative;
  transition: right 1s;
  right:0;
}

.bottom-link-group:hover .icon-left-open-big {
  right: 10px;
}

.bottom-link-group:hover .icon-right-open-big {
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="fuss-nav">
  <div class="container-fluid abstand pb-5">
    <div class="row no-gutters mx-sm-3 mx-md-2">

      <div class="col-3 px-1 col-sm-4">
        <a href="#" class="bottom-link-group">
          <i class="icon-left-open-big pfeil"><</i>
          <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">previous case</span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <a href="#" class="back-to-top">back to top</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3 px-1 col-sm-4 text-right">
        <a href="#" class="bottom-link-group">
          <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">next case</span>
          <i class="icon-right-open-big pfeil">></i>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```